# Environment SharePoint Online: Send SPD 2013 Workflow email notifications to Outlook mailboxes

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, outlook, send-email

Our current environment is SharePoint Online. Is there a way to add Outlook Mailbox email ID's to SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflows(Send an email). I tried to hard code the email ids but that didn't work. I guess it has to be SP groups or individual user email ids. Is there a workaround?

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible, but you need to configure the workflow for your web application in Central Admin as the following.

- Open Central Administration, Application Management > Manage web application, - Select your web application, from the above ribbon Click General settings > Workflow.
- Check Tes for `Allow external users to participate in workflow by sending them a copy of the document?`

[image]

> **Note:** Make sure you have configured Outgoing e-mail settings must be configured on the server.

Comment: Hello M.Qassas, Sorry I forgot to mention you. We are currently on Office 365 environment (SharePoint Online).  Do we have similar settings in O365?

Comment: No problem, unfortunately, no this setting for SP on-prem but let me check for a solution for SharePoint online, and feedback you :)

Comment: Hello M.Qassas, any luck with this?

Comment: Hello M.Qassas, please let me know if there is any update on this?

Comment: I am so sorry for late reply, but I actually searched for this and unfortunately, I didn't find any solution till now!